# Displaying 2 UISplitViewControllers interchangeably

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have 1 master split view controller (master-detail view) , however I want to show another split view controller interchangeably and transition between them.

So what I am currently doing is when I press a button on my first splitview's detail pane, it changes the controllers of the splitviewcontroller property.

`self.splitViewController.viewControllers  = vc.splitViewController.viewControllers;`

Now I want to display back the original splitview from my newly loaded controllers. I am able to achieve this by this piece of code:

```
    HomeLeftDetailViewController* mc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];
        UIViewController* dt = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RightViewController"];
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:mc, dt,nil];
```

I believe this is not a clean way to do this.

Any ideas?

**Update**

This is how I have fixed it.

I know this is not a good solution but it works, although later I might want to improve the memory issues this might have.

This is the code written at the Button Action in the Second SplitView Controller

```
HomeViewController* hvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen"];
UINavigationController *kkc = [hvc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
UIViewController *kkc2 = [hvc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
//  HomeLeftDetailViewController* mc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];
// dt = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:kkc, kkc2,nil];
```

HomeScreen is the identifier for the first splitview controller view.

I assume that `HomeViewController* hvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen"];` creates the master detail view however, `self.splitViewController.viewControllers = hvc.viewControllers` only assigns pointers and gets destroyed when the view is taken off screen.

I will update stuff about this if I find something more to share.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider having a top level view controller (generic) that handles launching the two split view controllers. Then, the button to switch vc's can ask the top level controller to dismiss the current split vc and launch the other one. Using segue you are ensured that your controllers are using memory efficiently (instantiated when needed, dealloc'ed when off screen). Good thing with this too is that you can link pretty much everything up in storyboard.

For the generic top level you might use a Navigation VC since you then get some convenience with toolbars, back buttons (optionally), etc.

Good luck,

Damien